# Spring security does not let me call end-point from mobile emulator

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

This is my spring security configuration

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(
                        "api/authenticate/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**",
                        "/register", "/api/addAdmin", "/api/authenticate", "/api/allAvailableTentsInExactTimeslotsRange",
                        "/actuator/**","/api/resident","/api/fetch-login-page"
                )
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS); // Tell Spring Security to  create sessions

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    // I don't want to do any hashing
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationmanager() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
}
```

This is my controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class LoginPageController {

    final LoginPageRepository loginPageRepository;

    final LoginPageServiceImpl loginPageServiceImpl;

    public LoginPageController(LoginPageRepository loginPageRepository, LoginPageServiceImpl loginPageServiceImpl) {
        this.loginPageRepository = loginPageRepository;
        this.loginPageServiceImpl = loginPageServiceImpl;
    }


   

    @ApiOperation(value = "Retrieve the login page customisation", response = LoginPageDto.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, response = LoginPageDto.class, message = "Successfully retrieved login page"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "You are not authorized to view the resource"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Accessing the resource you were trying to reach is forbidden"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The resource you were trying to reach is not found")})
    @GetMapping(value = "/fetch-login-page")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginPageDto> fetchLoginPage() {
        LoginPageDto tempLoginPageFto = loginPageServiceImpl.loginPageEntityToLoginPageDto(loginPageRepository.findFirstByLoginPageId(1L));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(tempLoginPageFto);
    }
}
```

If i call my end-point from swagger works like a charm without any authentication

[image]

However, when I try to call the end-point from my mobile emulator I get this error on server site:

```
2021-08-03 22:41:16.782 DEBUG 3088 --- [nio-8083-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/fetch-login-page/
2021-08-03 22:41:16.782 DEBUG 3088 --- [nio-8083-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2021-08-03 22:41:16.782 DEBUG 3088 --- [nio-8083-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2021-08-03 22:41:16.783 DEBUG 3088 --- [nio-8083-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /api/fetch-login-page/] with attributes [authenticated]
2021-08-03 22:41:16.783 DEBUG 3088 --- [nio-8083-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2021-08-03 22:41:16.783 DEBUG 3088 --- [nio-8083-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-08-03 22:41:16.783 DEBUG 3088 --- [nio-8083-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2021-08-03 22:41:16.783 DEBUG 3088 --- [nio-8083-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2021-08-03 22:41:16.783 DEBUG 3088 --- [nio-8083-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2021-08-03 22:41:16.783 DEBUG 3088 --- [nio-8083-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2021-08-03 22:41:16.786 DEBUG 3088 --- [nio-8083-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

In Android App I do the calls with retrofit. I know that I have to use the actuall ip from my pc to make this work. In fact I have a lot of apps without spring security enabled that works perfect.

On android studio, this is my retrofit configuration:

```
public class RetrofitConfig {

    public static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.1:8083/api/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

and this is my API class

```
public interface myAPI {

    @GET("fetch-login-page/")
    Call<MainActivityModel> fetchLoginPage();

}
```

and here I implement the actual call

```
public void fetchLoginPage() {
    MyAPI myAPI = RetrofitConfig.getClient().create(MyAPI.class);
    Call<MainActivityModel> call = myAPI.fetchLoginPage();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<MainActivityModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MainActivityModel> call, Response<MainActivityModel> response) {
          

            textViewOtp.setText(response.body().getTextViewOtp());
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(response.body().getSupportActionBarString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MainActivityModel> call, Throwable t) {
            t.getStackTrace();


        }
    });
}
```

on client side I get 403

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=403, message=, url=http://192.168.1.1:8083/api/fetch-login-page/}
```

Could you please tell me what configuration am I missing from spring-security? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was really easy after all.
In the srping security in antMatchers I had put

```
/api/fetch-login-page
```

but in my call, I was calling

```
/api/fetch-login-page/
```

with "/" at the end. Changed my call to the exact url and everything works.